# How do I add start parameter to a program installed via snap

Tags: snap, 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and want to add a few starting parameters to a program installed as a snap package.

The programm (Gitter) is in my dash and i want it to start with the parameter --force-device-scale-factor=2

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution.

Go to folder /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications and right click
"gitter-desktop_gitter-desktop.desktop" and open properties.

The command must change from this

env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/gitter-desktop_gitter-desktop.desktop /snap/bin/gitter-desktop %U

to this

env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/gitter-desktop_gitter-desktop.desktop /snap/bin/gitter-desktop **--force-device-scale-factor=2** %U

Comment: This only works as root. If you open the file from terminal (e.g. vim) look for lines starting with `Exec=` there might be more than one it the application has a menu.

Comment: This is going to get overwritten as soon as your snap is updated, which happens frequently and automatically.  Instead, you should copy the file to either `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/local/share/applications` for multi-user.  Snap desktop files are registered last, so your new file will override it.